# Like putting icon and text in tabs (Sliding Tabs) android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design

I need to make my application with this appearance (icon and text): https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsbHJuWi04N0ZIc0E/components_tabs_usage_mobile7.png

But so far I can only leave it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK5aC.png

How can I fix this?

Follow my xml tabs:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android: layout_width = "match_parent"
    android: layout_height = "match_parent"
    android: gravity = "center">

        <ImageView
            android: id = "@ + id / imgTab"
            android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android: TEXTSIZE = "14sp"
            android: textColor = "@ android: color / white"
            android: id = "@ + id / tv_tab"
            android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android: layout_height = "wrap_content" />


</ LinearLayout>
```

Method in the fragment (Tab):

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) {

    Drawable tab = mContext.getResources () getDrawable (icons [position]).;
            tab.setBounds (0, 0, heightIcon, heightIcon);



            ImageSpan ImageSpan is = new (tab);
            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString (titles [position]);
            sp.setSpan (s, sp.length () - 1, sp.length (), 0);

            return sp;
```

I tried to follow [Need to center-align a single portion of text in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818654/need-to-center-align-a-single-portion-of-text-in-a-textview) but it did not work for me :(

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534420/how-can-i-develop-the-pagerslidingtabstrip-with-images-in-android/29535378#29535378) and follow it properly.

A little change here will do the trick:

```
 Drawable image = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
 SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" \n"+"hello");
 ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
 sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 return sb;
```

in place of the "hello" use your title.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Vote up my answer in the link if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your task with the following very easily.
Firstly create new XML under Layout Folder. Give it name [**custom_tab_view**]  then paste the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <!--<com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ripple:rv_centered="true">-->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|center" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And now went to your **ViewPageAdapter** and Replace your Function [**CharSequence**] with below code.

```
 // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //return Titles[position];
        Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        //image.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 64);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);


        return sb;
    }
```

and in the **MainActivity** under **OnCreate** put this line if it is not already there.

```
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
tabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);


                                                 Hope it answer the Question.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the default **Tabbed Activity** from android studio, just add the following:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.image_1);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.image_2);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.image_3);
```